# Is a small vocabulary for Neural Nets ok?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am designing a neural network to try and generate music. The neural network would be a 2 layered LSTM (Long Short Term Memory). 
I am hoping to encode the music into a many-hot format for training, ie it would be a 1 if that note was playing and a 0 if that note was not playing. 
Here is an excerpt of what this data would look like:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000100100001000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000100100001000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000100100001000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000100100001000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000100100001000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011010100100001010000000000000000000000
```

There are 88 columns which represent 88 notes and each now represents a new beat. The output will be at a character level.

I am just wondering since there are only 2 characters in the vocabulary, would the probability of a 0 being next *always* be higher than the probability of a 1 being next?
I know for a large vocabulary, a large training set is needed, but I only have a small vocabulary. I have 229 files which corresponds to about 50,000 lines of text. Is this enough to prevent the output being all 0s?

Also, would it be better to have 88 nodes, 1 for each note, or just one node for one character at a time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A small vocabulary is fine as long as your dataset not skewed overwhelmingly to one of the "words".

As to "would it be better to have 88 nodes, 1 for each note, or just one node for one character at a time?", each timestep is represented as 88 characters. Each character is a feature of that timestep. Your LSTM should be outputting the next timestep, so you should have 88 nodes. Each node should output the probability of that node being present in that timestep.

Finally since you are building a Char-RNN I would strongly suggest using [abc notation](http://abcnotation.com) to represent your data. A song in ABC notation looks like this:

```
X:1
T:Speed the Plough
M:4/4
C:Trad.
K:G
|:GABc dedB|dedB dedB|c2ec B2dB|c2A2 A2BA|
  GABc dedB|dedB dedB|c2ec B2dB|A2F2 G4:|
|:g2gf gdBd|g2f2 e2d2|c2ec B2dB|c2A2 A2df|
  g2gf g2Bd|g2f2 e2d2|c2ec B2dB|A2F2 G4:|
```

This is perfect for Char-RNNs because it represents every song as a set of of characters, and you can run conversions from MIDI to ABC and vice versa. All you have to do is train your model to predict the next character in this sequence instead of dealing with 88 output nodes.

Comment: As mine is just 0s and 1s, would that be very skewed towards the 0s?

Comment: No as long as your data has a good number of both ones and zeros.